# Laravel : how to delete a single entry in many to many relation (morph)

Tags: laravel, pivot, where-clause, many-to-many, relationship

I have 2 models : Application and Contact.  I use a polymorphic relation "contactable".

A contact can be referenced to many applications (or other modeles), and can be referenced many times to the same application.
In this case, the relations shares the same values for contact_id && contactable_id, but have different role properties. A contact can have multiples roles within the same application.

I use a ApplicationContactController to handle the update of the relation, but **I can't delete the single entry** based on role = null propertie.

I tried to implement this code but it removes all the entries that macth contact_id/contactable_id given in route :

`public function updateRelation(Request $request, Application $application, Contact $contact)
{

```
    // dd($request->all() );
    $validated = $request->validate([
        'role' => 'sometimes|string|nullable',
        'note' => 'sometimes|string',
    ]);




    if ($validated['role'] === null) { // I want to delete only the good one line based on $request->old_role

        $rels = $application->contacts()
        ->wherePivot('contact_id', $contact->id)
        ->get();



        foreach($rels as $item) {
        //    dump($item->pivot->role);

            if ($item->pivot->role === $request->old_role) {
                dump('match', $item->pivot->role, $request->old_role);

                    $pivot = $item->pivot;
                    $pivot->delete();
            } else {
                dump('no-match', $item->pivot->role, $request->old_role);
            }

            // if
        }

        
    } else { // update works : I can update only the good line based on old_role request :)

        
        $application->contacts()
        ->where('contact_id', $contact->id)
        ->wherePivot('role', $request->old_role)
        ->updateExistingPivot($contact->id, $validated);
    }


    return response()->json([
        'message' => 'Role updated',
    ]);
}`
```

I expected the line with contact_id && contactable_id && role == old_role to be deleted, and the others contact_id && contactable_id && role != old_role (if exists) remains

Answer (score 0):

According to the doc MorphToMany works the same way ManyToMany does.
Didn't try it myself but `attach()` `detach` & `sync` should be available

```php
$application->contact()->detach($contact->id)
```

Comment: Thanks Charlie.
I've already tried that but `$application->contact()->detach($contact->id)` deletes all related Contact & Application. 
I can have same/multiple contact_id AND contactable_id key with different role propertie and $application->contact()->detach($contact->id) removes all the contact entries with that application.

Comment: Sorry to hear that, maybe it's a bug because `detach($id)` really should remove only 1 row in the pivot table (assuming `$id` is not null, can you check that $contact->id is not null ?). Can you share how the relation is defined ?

Comment: Hey Charlie, thank you again.

I used the ->wherePivot('role', $request->old_role) clause and it seems working !

I'm aware that if multiple relations has same contact_id && contactable && role they will be delete but it makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

It seems working with wherePivot() clause to target the only good one and detach() :

```
if ($validated['role'] === null) { // delete

       
        $application->contacts()
            ->wherePivot('role', $request->old_role)
            ->detach($contact->id);


    } else { // update

        $application->contacts()
        ->where('contact_id', $contact->id)
        ->wherePivot('role', $request->old_role)
        ->updateExistingPivot($contact->id, $validated);
    }
```

Thanks Charlie for your support